# LANDSAT-7 strange strip on SWIR bands (B5 and B7)

Tags: landsat, band, reflectance, values, sentinel-hub

I was exploring Landsat 7 data on SentinelHub and came across with this strange strip in the SWIR band B7 (also B5):

[image]

By placing a pin in this strip and exploring the stats, I found that there is no other occurrence over several years that reaches 1.3:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know the reason for this strip with high values?

Comment: Maybe see here?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84319/destriping-landsat-7-images

Comment: In the question that you sent I think they refer to strips without data, in the one I present the strip has values, although high.